# Font size on Java (measure unit)

Tags: java, fonts, size

In this Font class constructor you can pass a size by an argument:

```
Font(String name, int style, int size)
```

Is this size in pt, px, ...? Can you solve my doubt; and do a brief explanation about how this unit of measure works?

Comment: The documentation says "point size", so it means "pt".

Answer (score 0):

> The point size of this Font, rounded to integer.

[Source:JavaApi](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html)